# How can I calculate the number of lost weather days in Excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have done some programming in the past, so I would be able to figure this problem out in a programming language. But, I do not know how to proceed with accomplishing my task in an Excel spreadsheet. Any kind of guidance would be helpful because I am not familiar with anything but a basic use of MS Excel, so I don't even know which topics to search for to get some guidance on solving this problem.

Here is the breakdown for my problem:

I work for a construction company and I am keeping count of the number of days which need to be extended to a schedule deadline. All "lost weather days" are in a column (assume they are in chronological order and there are not bad dates like 2/32/22).

Contractually, we eat the first 5 lost weather days for any given month. But, if there are more than 5 lost weather days in any given month, then I need to add those days to a count by which the schedule deadline can be extended. So, any time a month has more than 5 lost weather days, I need to start counting.

For example:

| **DATE** |
| --- |
| 1/1/23 |
| 1/2/23 |
| 1/13/23 |
| 1/14/23 |
| 1/25/23 |
| **1/26/23** |
| **1/27/23** |
| 2/1/23 |
| 2/12/23 |

Here, 1/6/23 and 1/7/23 need to be counted while all of the other dates are ignored because 1/1/22, 1/2/22, 1/3/22, 1/4/22, and 1/5/22 are the first five days in January 2023.  So, I should have a cell with a value of 2.

Any help or guidance would be appreciated. Thank you.

I haven't tried anything specific because I am unfamiliar with excel at the moment.

Comment: Greater than 5 days in a month or greater than the fifth day of the month?  As in if the range starts on the 10th-18th we would count 4 or would it be 9?

Comment: Lets say the dates were 1/1/22, 1/5/22, 1/7/22, 1/20/22, 1/21/22, 1/23/22, 1/24/22, 2/1/22, and 2/2/22. That is a total of 9 days, but because there were 7 days in january, i need to count the number of days in january 2022 greater than 5 lost days in january.

In this particular case, the result I am looking for is 2 days because jan 2022 has 7 lost weather days and I need to count any lost weather day beyond the 5th lost day.

Comment: The situation is that I am counting the number of lost weather days for a construction company. They eat the first 5 weather days of any given month (bc that's what's in their contract), but I need to count any days beyond the 5th lost day of any given month so I can add them as an extension to the schedule.

Comment: The frequency function groups numbers and summarizes it. If there's a range of `{1,1,1,2,2,3,3,3}` it'll summarize the first occurance of a group (in this case `1`) and shows it's total count (`3`). All following of the same group will show as `0`. So 1 occurring 3 times, 2 - 2 times, 3 - 3 times results in array: `{3,0,0,2,0,3,0,0,0}` (there's always a trailing zero in the array, hence the 3 zero's at `3`. (Oops wrong place, but you got the deal).

Answer (score 2):

```
=LET(m,EOMONTH(TRANSPOSE(A2:A10),0),
     f,FREQUENCY(m,m),
SUM(IF(f>5,f-5)))
```

This first converts the dates in the same month(/year) to the same date being the end of that month.
Then `FREQUENCY` counts the number of days being the same per month. Then, if the frequency is higher than 5, 5 is substracted, else ignored.

For older Excel versions:

```
=SUM( 
     IF(
        FREQUENCY(               
                  EOMONTH(TRANSPOSE(A2:A10),0),                
                  EOMONTH(TRANSPOSE(A2:A10),0)
                 )>5,
        FREQUENCY(               
                  EOMONTH(TRANSPOSE(A2:A10),0),                
                  EOMONTH(TRANSPOSE(A2:A10),0)
        )-5)
    )
```

Comment: Glad to be of service. I liked your question.

Comment: This seems like a clever solution, but I don't know what a bins_array is and a quick google search isn't giving me the answer. Can you please briefly explain to me what a bins_array is?

Comment: nevermind, i got it. i like this solution a lot, it's clever

Comment: PS the reason for transposing the range for the EDATE function is because it won't work otherwise. Not sure why, but experience.

Answer (score 1):

With Office 365:

```
=LET(rng,A2:A10,uq,UNIQUE(DATE(YEAR(rng),MONTH(rng),1)),SUM(BYROW(uq,LAMBDA(a,MAX(0,COUNTIFS(A2:A10,">="&a,A2:A10,"<"&EOMONTH(a,0)+1)-5)))))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I'll spend some time dissecting this answer and trying to understand it. I appreciate your help.

Comment: It basically creates and array of unique month/year.  Then uses that in the countifs row by row.  Then we subtract 5 from the total count for that month year and return the max of that number and 0 so we do not go negative.  Then sum the resulting array.

Comment: Just about everything I have learned I have learned here, by lurking and trying to answer.

Comment: Thank you very much. 

Moving along with this example, what are the operators for me to combine multiple ranges into the same array?

For example, how would I generate the same single array, but from multiple columns such as A1:A10, C1:C10, and E1:10?

Comment: I haven't used stack overflow since I was helping other people answer questions in C when I was college. I forgot what this was like. Again, thank you very much. I appreciate your help. Having guidance from people who know what they're doing is very helpful.

Comment: That would be a new question, but look into VSTACK

Comment: Thank you. The information you gave me opened the door for me to understand how to accomplish what I wanted. I appreciate your time. I don't have a lot of time to be playing with this stuff, but I've been playing with it and I fully understand the function you gave me the other day. So, thanks again. I appreciate your help.